# Understanding MVC SQL query. From, where, then select

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I inherited the code below and was hoping someone could explain it to me. The model definition is fine, but I am not understanding the string Minor1 setup. The SQL query looks backwards. Is this a normal practice? I tried putting the query in the normal order (select, from, where) and it did not work.

```
Example for model:
[Table("MINORS")]
public class VerifyDataModel_MINORS
{
    [Key]
    public string MINORS_ID { get; set; }
    public string MINORS_DESC { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
            string Minor1 = (from A in db.VerifyDataModel_STUDENT_PROGRAM
                             join B in db.VerifyDataModel_STPR_STATUS on A.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID equals B.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID into AB
                             from AB1 in AB.Where(B => B.POS == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join C in db.VerifyDataModel_STPR_MINOR_LISTS on A.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID equals C.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID into ABC
                             from ABC1 in ABC.Where(C => C.STPR_MINORS.Substring(0, 2) != "XX").DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join D in db.VerifyDataModel_MINOR on ABC1.STPR_MINORS equals D.MINORS_ID into ABCD
                             from ABCD1 in ABCD.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where AB1.STPR_STATUS == "A"
                             where ABC1.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID.Substring(8, 5) != "GENED"
                             where A.STUDENT_PROGRAMS_ID.Substring(0, 7) == personId
                             where ABC1.STPR_MINOR_END_DATE == null
                             select ABCD1.MINORS_DESC).Min();
```

Comment: This is not an SQL query. This is [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries). It is used to query collections.

Comment: Thank you so much!!